# How to do DataBinding for ControlTemplates in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Disclaimer: I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and Xaml in general

I'm trying to figure out how DataBinding works within templates in Xamarin.Forms.

**Xaml:**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridItem">
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ContentView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="15">
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </ContentView>
              <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{TemplateBinding LabelText}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#8B0000" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentView x:Name="randomButton1" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource GridItem}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <ContentView x:Name="randomButton2" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource GridItem}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

**C# Code behind**
    using Xamarin.Forms;

```
namespace TestApp.XForms
{
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly MainButtonViewModel[] buttons;

        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            randomButton1.BindingContext = new MainButtonViewModel("some text1", "someimage1.png");
            randomButton2.BindingContext = new MainButtonViewModel("some text2", "someimage2.png");
        }
    }

    public class MainButtonViewModel : BindableObject
    {
        private string labelText;
        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return labelText; }
            set
            {
                labelText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string imageSource;
        public string ImageSource
        {
            get { return imageSource; }
            set
            {
                imageSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainButtonViewModel()
        {
        }
        public MainButtonViewModel(string text, string imageLocation)
        {
            LabelText = text;
            ImageSource = imageLocation;
        }
    }
}
```

So my templates seem to work. I see 2 red blocks. But none of the bindings seem to have worked. Everything is empty:
[image]

How can I get the data binding to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your view model doesn't support `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You could use `Xamarin.Forms` class:

```
public class SomeViewModel : BindableObject
```

And then you could notify UI, that some property has been changed:

```
        private string _someStringProperty;
        public string SomeStringProperty
        {
            get { return _someStringProperty; }
            set
            {
                _someStringProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Also will be helpful [Binding from `ControlTemplate`.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/template-binding/)

Comment: I'm guessing this is for 2-way binding. I only need 1-way binding. I just tried this anyway but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: `TwoWay` binding is when UI tells view model, that something has been changed. I think, that when you will return some value from property it could work w/o implementing an interface: `public string LabelText { get { retutn "Alloha" } }`

Comment: I updated my post with the BindableObject. It didn't fix my problem. I also tried hardcoding a string in the getter of the LabelText. That also didn't work for me. The label is still empty. I also tried Binding instead of TemplateBinding since I don't know which one is correct. That also didn't work

Comment: Due to [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/template-binding/) `ContentPage` has `BindableProperty` and you should bind to them from your `Template`. [Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Templates/ControlTemplates/SimpleThemeWithTemplateBindingAndViewModel).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ControlTemplate` it requires `TemplateBinding` for `BindingContext`, otherwise it won't have any `BindingContext` itself. You can use `DataTemplate` without setting `BindingContext`, it inherits parent's `BindingContext` itself.

i.e:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="yourTemplate" BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}">
  <Grid>
    <!--Your Template-->
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="yourTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <!--Your Template-->
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```